# Parse multiple substrings from a column using markers and place them into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I created a dataframe column called **LogEntry** which extracts all the log entries from a text file that I'm interested in (using str.contains).

I am completely stuck on finding the best method (or any method) for parsing values from the LogEntry column and put them into new columns such as: position_nm, target_nm, position_error_nm, pump_dist, and pump_startpos, so that the output data frame will look like this:

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN6zS.png)

I tried using re.search, but the position_nm column remained blank.

```
 try:
     df['position_nm'] = df.LogEntry.re.search('position_nm":(.+?),' df['LogEntry']).group(1)
 except AttributeError:
     df['position_nm'] = ''
```

Any help to get me going would be much appreciated. I am new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the log entry text?

Comment: @wwnde "2020-03-03 02:30:42.1858||INFO|EmbeddedSystemCommunicationLogger|IxIn|Line 51|Imb {"IxType":"ix_zstage_motion_complete","IxID":-1,"position_nm":3400091,"target_nm":3400000,"position_error_nm":91,"vel_stall_flag":false,"pwm_ave_stall_flag":false,"pwm_instant_stall_flag":false}"

Comment: See my answer. You didn't provide all the test so I worked with what I had. Happy to assist further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expected to see the whole text but you gave me only abit. Happy toimprove it if you add text. For now;

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'s':['2020-03-03 02:30:42.1858||INFO|EmbeddedSystemCommunicationLogger|IxIn|Line 51|Imb {"IxType":"ix_zstage_motion_complete","IxID":-1,"position_nm":3400091,"target_nm":3400000,"position_error_nm":91,"vel_stall_flag":false,"pwm_ave_stall_flag":false,"pwm_instant_stall_flag":false']})
df
```

Extract any text  which immediately follows _ 2 lower case alphabet in this case_nm, " and : in that order into df2. After extraction, I transpose the result because it comes as vertical rows

```
df2=df['s'].str.extractall('((?<=\_[a-z]{2}\"\:)\d+)').T
```

Merge df and df2 and set the column names

```
df3=df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df3.columns=['LogEntry','position_nm','target_nm','position_error_nm']
df3
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for each of the features as follows and then apply lambda function to the dataframe.

```
def position_nm(sample):
    sdict = '{'+sample.split('{')[1]
    sdict = json.loads(sdict)
    return sdict['position_nm']

df['position_nm'] = df['LogEntry'].apply(lambda x : position_nm(x))
```